# Yocto devtool get /usr/src in recipe-sysroot for debugging

Tags: debugging, sdk, yocto

I'm trying to debug my application on the target device. I'm using gdb-multiarch on the host and gdb-server on the target. Everything works fine with breakpoints and stepping.

My Problem is that my application is dependent on some of my on libs. When I step into a function of these libs the source code is not found. There is no /usr/src in my recipe-sysroot folder.

Steps I have done:

1. Generate eSDK: `bitbake my-image -c populate_sdk_ext`
2. Installed the eSDK to `~/my_sdk`
3. `devtool modify -n my-recipe ~/repositories/my-application`
4. `devtool build my-recipe`

When I check the my-image.tar.gz generated by bitbake then I can find all the /usr/src folder. But the eSDK and devtool don't extract the files to the recipe-sysroot. How can I get this done? Is there an option I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

did you try to use devtool add to add the source ? in yocto the packages are usually debug free and source free, for example net-utils have net-util, netutil-dbg, net-util-dev and net-util-src.